# How can I divide $x^3 \over x^2 +1$ using long division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^3 \over x^2 +1$$

I have the answer as $x -{1 \over x}$ so far but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: use the fact that $x^3 = x^3 + x - x = x(x^2+1) - x$

Comment: It might make more sense to ask one somewhat general question rather than yet another isolated example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.............................................................

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, I was trying to put the x^2 into the x and so I had x - 1/x which I see was the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: @Jay you' re welcome

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, your result is *not* correct. Rather, $$\frac{x^3}{x^2 +1}  = \frac{x^3 + x - x}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{x(x^2 + 1)- x}{x^2 + 1}  = x -\frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Or use the Remainder theorem.

x^3 = ( Ax + B ) (x^2 +1 ) + ( Px + Q)

By equating coefficients,

A = 1
B = 0
Q = 0
A+P = 0
P = -1

x ^3 = x ( x^2 +1) - x